# Update specific node in database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Thanks for the previous help, I managed to write to the firebase database, the problem now is that **I can't take the specific node to edit.**

When opening an element from a  `recyclerview`  and obtaining the data and modifying the  `interno`   value and pressing  `update button` , **the database checks it but saves it outside the uid of the selected cow**. You can see it better in the image.

[image]

This is the code where im trying to do the `update`. I've been testing and may have missing or leftover code, sorry. I do it only with `interno` as a test to later add the rest of the keys

```
  private void Update() {
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Vacas");
        String key = ref.child("Vacas").push().getKey();
        Cow cow = new Cow();
        Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        updates.put("interno", tvinterno.getText().toString());
        ref.updateChildren(updates);
    }
```

I am not taking the reference correctly, I hope you can help me solve this problem, thank you

**EDIT**

I am using the `database` in a `recyclerview`, you can see in the image, when I click on a `cow`, a **new activity opens with all the information in the database, this is where I am interested in editing the values** ​​( Attached image).

**I want to edit the values ​​based on the selected cow from the app**, this is where I don't know if the solution you proposed to Mr. HaroldSer and Mr. Arup will work

**EDIT 2**

This is how I set the values ​​in the `Edit activity`

in my `adapter` in the `onBindViewHolder`, I send them to the `Edit activity` through an `intent`

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final cowviewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Cow vacaslist = vacas.get(position);
        holder.textViewinterno.setText(vacaslist.interno);
        holder.textViewsiniiga.setText(vacaslist.siniiga);
        String url= vacaslist.getUrl();

        if (url == null|| url.isEmpty()){
            holder.imageviewrec.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_imageinf);
        } else {
            Picasso.get().load(vacaslist.getUrl()).error(R.drawable.ic_imageinf).into(holder.imageviewrec);
        }


        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Cowdetail.class);
                intent.putExtra("keyint", vacaslist.getInterno());
                intent.putExtra("keysin", vacaslist.getSiniiga());
                intent.putExtra("madre", vacaslist.getMadre());
                intent.putExtra("padre", vacaslist.getPadre());
                intent.putExtra("nacimiento", vacaslist.getNacimiento());
                intent.putExtra("toro", vacaslist.getToro());
                intent.putExtra("estatus", vacaslist.getEstatus());
                intent.putExtra("inseminacion", vacaslist.getInseminacion());
                intent.putExtra("notas", vacaslist.getNotas());
                intent.putExtra("img", url);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

in this way I set them in Edit activity (Cowdetail)

```
public class Cowdetail extends AppCompatActivity {
  
    EditText tvinterno, tvsiniiga, tvpadre, tvmadre, tvnacimiento, tvinseminacion, tvtoro, tvestatus, tvnotas;
    AppCompatImageView tvimage;
    Button tvbutton;
    String cow_key;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detailcow);
        

        tvinterno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvinterno);
        tvsiniiga = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvsiniiga);
        tvpadre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvpadre);
        tvmadre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvmadre);
        tvnacimiento = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvnacimiento);
        tvinseminacion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvinsemincion);
        tvtoro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvtoro);
        tvestatus = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvestatus);
        tvnotas = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvnotas);
        tvimage = (AppCompatImageView) findViewById(R.id.tvimage);
        tvbutton = findViewById(R.id.actualizar);

        String vpadre = "";
        String vmadre = "";
        String vinterno = "";
        String vsiniiga = "";
        String vnacimiento = "";
        String vinseminacion = "";
        String vtoro = "";
        String vestatus = "";
        String vnotas = "";
        String vurl;


        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras !=null);
        vinterno = extras.getString("keyint");
        vsiniiga = extras.getString("keysin");
        vmadre = extras.getString("madre");
        vpadre = extras.getString("padre");
        vnacimiento = extras.getString("nacimiento");
        vinseminacion = extras.getString("inseminacion");
        vtoro = extras.getString("toro");
        vestatus = extras.getString("estatus");
        vnotas = extras.getString("notas");
        String image = extras.getString("img");
        if (image == null|| image.isEmpty()){
            tvimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_imageinf);
        } else {
            Picasso.get().load(image).fit().centerCrop().into(tvimage);
        }



        tvpadre.setText(vpadre);
        tvinterno.setText(vinterno);
        tvsiniiga.setText(vsiniiga);
        tvmadre.setText(vmadre);
        tvnacimiento.setText(vnacimiento);
        tvinseminacion.setText(vinseminacion);
        tvtoro.setText(vtoro);
        tvestatus.setText(vestatus);
        tvnotas.setText(vnotas);

        tvbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Update();
            }
        });

    }

    private void Update() {
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Vacas");
        String key = ref.child("interno").getKey();
        Cow cow = new Cow();
        Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        updates.put("interno", tvinterno.getText().toString());
        ref.child(key).updateChildren(updates)
      }

}
```

**EDIT 3**

this is how i add the `node_id` to `onDataChange`

```
  mReferenceCow.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                vacas.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 :
                        snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Cow vaca = snapshot1.getValue(Cow.class);
                    vaca.setNode_id(snapshot.getKey());
                    vacas.add(vaca);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }

        });
```

The rest of the code you told me, I did it as is, except in the `ref`, because if I don't add -- "  " -- to the `node_id` it marks an error

`ref.child("node_id").updateChildren(updates)`

this keeps happening

[image]

**EDIT 4**

With this code i can get the `interno` value and edit it from the app. But now the problem is when I enter from the app to edit the `interno` value of a single node, it is changed in all nodes

```
private void Update() {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        reference.child("Vacas").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot datas: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    String key = datas.getKey();

                    Map<String, Object> update = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    update.put("interno", tvinterno.getText().toString());
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Vacas")
                            .child(key).updateChildren(update);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Did you check if your getting cow id ?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I changed the `EditActivity` for a `Dialogplus` in `onBindViewHolder` of my `AdapterActivity`. Here i setted my information and using `Hashmap` for update the specific nodes.

```
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final DialogPlus dialogPlus = DialogPlus.newDialog(holder.imageviewrec.getContext())
                            .setContentHolder(new com.orhanobut.dialogplus.ViewHolder(R.layout.dialog_detail))
                            .setExpanded(true, 2000)
                            .create();
                    View myview = dialogPlus.getHolderView();
                    final EditText interno = myview.findViewById(R.id.dinterno);
                    final EditText siniiga = myview.findViewById(R.id.dsiniiga);



                   interno.setText(model.getInterno());
                   siniiga.setText(model.getSiniiga());

                   dialogPlus.show();

                        update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                                map.put("interno", interno.getText().toString());
                                map.put("siniiga", siniiga.getText().toString());

                                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Vacas")
                                        .child(getRef(position).getKey()).updateChildren(map)
                                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                                dialogPlus.dismiss();
                                            }
                                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                dialogPlus.dismiss();
                                            }
                                });
                            }
                        });



                }

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong you want to `update` your existing data in firebase right? If this is the case then

`I am not taking the reference correctly` Yes

Try this

**EDIT**
Add `node_id` field to `vacaslist` pojo class and generate `Getter` and `Setter`.

Now add `vacaslist.setNode_id(snapshot.getKey());` in `onDataChange` where you are setting data for recycler view.

Add this `intent.putExtra("node_id", vacaslist.getNode_id());` to your `onBindViewHolder`

Get the value in `EditActivity` `String node_id = extras.getString("node_id");`

First take the reference
`DatabaseReference dRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Vacas");`

For example Now I want to update `interno` in `1717` child node then I'll do in this way

```
private void Update() {
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Vacas");
        HashMap<String, Object> updates = new HashMap();
        updates.put("interno", tvinterno.getText().toString());
        dRef.child(node_id).updateChildren(updates);
      }
```

Comment: What do I need to do with "cow_key", declare it as `String unique_key;`? because I did that nothing happens, or what is the correct way?

Comment: Thanks for answering. i have seen previously the answer you propose, but i don't know if it will work with my project, because if i want to edit another `interno` in another child node i will need to change the `1717` to `1836`, for example? 

I will add more information about my project.

Comment: Okay...
Can you please tell me how you set values in `Edit activity`?

Comment: of course, I will also add it to the question

Comment: Hi sorry but I'm still doing something wrong, I will add `onDataChange` if you can take a look at it I would appreciate it. I could upload the whole project to github or something like that, if you want to see it more closely. I really appreciate your help

Comment: you have to also pass `node_id` from `onBindViewHolder` like you do for `img, notas` etc. then get `node_id` in `EditActivity` like `String node_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("node_id");` 
Then use `ref.child(node_id).updateChildren(updates)` not `ref.child("node_id").updateChildren(updates)`  because node_id is a variable.

You should also declare `node_id` as globle variable on `EditActivity`

Comment: Hi, I've been testing in a slightly different way. I can get the `interno` value and edit it, but now I edit all the nodes in the database. I'll leave you the code and an image of the database. I hope you can help me, thank you.

Comment: `but now I edit all the nodes in the database` it's pretty obvious just think what you write in your `update()`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update below code:

from:

```
ref.updateChildren(updates);
```

to:

```
ref.child(cow_key).updateChildren(updates);
```

where cow_key is one of the cow's key such as: "1717" or "1836".

Comment: What do I need to do with "cow_key", declare it as `String cow_key;`? because I did that nothing happens, or what is the correct way?